# Can I view past clans in Clash Royale?

Tags: clash-royale

The question is that simple, I want to find previous clans I’ve been in. I’ve looked everywhere on Stats Royale but can’t seem to view past clans, only my current clan and everyone in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clash Royale does not provide any clan history of any kind.

---

However, there are some sites that scape information like that to create some sort of history.

For example, the [RoyaleApi](https://royaleapi.com) player page has a 'Clan History' tab that looks like:

[image]
<sub>Screenshot is of a random top 100 player's [profile](https://royaleapi.com/player/Y8YVUVL9).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Well, in short, I don't think you can. Not unless you have screenshots, some out-of-game records of your previous clan, etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).